# Toolbar icons unable to load when running Emacs through xhost from FreeBSD to Ubuntu

Tags: images, ssh, menu-bar, x11

I'm connected to a FreeBSD Computer using `ssh [ip] -X`, and emacs launches just fine, but this happens and all the icons are little pieces of paper with red X's:

```
> emacs

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'document-new' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'document-open' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'image-missing' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'window-close' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'document-save' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-undo' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-cut' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-copy' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-paste' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure

(emacs:22812): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure

(emacs:22812): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-find' for stock: Internal error: Image loader module 'png' failed to complete an operation, but didn't give a reason for the failure
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening? GVIM loads just fine.